# Как импортировать json-файл с сервера и обработать данные в DRF (python)?

Tags: python, json, django-rest-framework

Есть файл books.json. Необходимо сделать следующее:

1. Данный файл должен запрашиваться по сети.
2. Изображения должны сохраняться в проекте.
3. При повторном парсинге не должно возникать дубликатов.
4. Если нет категории - добавлять в "Новинки".
5. Файл содержит намеренные ошибки в данных.

Пример данных:

```
    {
"title": "Unlocking Android",
"isbn": "1933988673",
"pageCount": 416,
"publishedDate": { "$date": "2009-04-01T00:00:00.000-0700" },
"thumbnailUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/AKIAJC5RLADLUMVRPFDQ.book-thumb-images/ableson.jpg",
"shortDescription": "Unlocking Android: A Developer's Guide provides concise, hands-on instruction for the Android operating system and development tools.",
"longDescription": "Android is an open source mobile phone platform based on the Linux operating system and developed by the Open Handset Alliance, a consortium of over 30 hardware, software and telecom companies that focus on open standards for mobile devices.",
"status": "PUBLISH",
"authors": ["W. Frank Ableson", "Charlie Collins", "Robi Sen"],
"categories": ["Open Source", "Mobile"]
    }
```

Моя модель, написанная по данным:

```
class Book(models.Model):
"""Model of books"""
title = models.TextField(max_length=100,)
isbn = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True,)
pageCount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    validators=[MinValueValidator(1), ],)
publishedDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
thumbnailUrl = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='books/',
)
shortDescription = models.CharField(max_length=1000,)
longDescription = models.TextField()
status = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
authors = models.ManyToManyField(
    Author, related_name='author_of_book',
)
categories = models.ManyToManyField(
    Category, related_name='category_of_book',
)
```

Как получить и обработать данные из json-файла?

Comment: Получить - через модуль `requests`. Обработать - как обычный словарь.